# Did ISIS ever attack or threaten to attack Israel?

Tags: israel, islamic-state

Any Muslim militant group I know of are against Israel. However, I never heard of ISIS saying or doing anything against Israel or its Interest.

Can you point any one incident out?

If not, why is it unavailable?

Comment: Nothing against Israel's *interests*? Even if we ignore the attacks against Israel itself mentioned in the answer, which a simple search online should have found, it should be rather clear that it is not in Israel's interest, nor indeed that of any country in the region, to have a war on its borders, which ISIS's actions and mission (a worldwide caliphate not accepted by other countries) necessarily imply.

Comment: Do any of the following posts answer your "question"? https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/10394/why-does-daesh-not-attack-or-even-threaten-to-attack-israel or https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/10414/why-isn-t-israel-fighting-isis or https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/11744/why-hasn%C2%B4t-israel-been-a-victim-of-is-terror-so-far

Answer (score 4):

From the ADL (April 5, 2022):
"A week of violent Islamist extremist attacks in Israel beginning on March 22, 2022, left 11 people dead and many more wounded. The Islamic State in Iraq and Syria (ISIS) claimed responsibility for two of the attacks, and released a video of two of the terrorists swearing an oath of allegiance to the terrorist group in a video released online."

https://www.adl.org/resources/blog/isis-connected-recent-terror-attacks-israel

From CNN (March 28, 2022):
"ISIS operatives killed two people and injured six in a shooting attack Sunday in the Israeli city of Hadera, some 31 miles north of Tel Aviv, Israeli officials said. "

https://www.cnn.com/2022/03/28/middleeast/israel-isis-attack-intl/index.html

From i24News (April 18, 2022):
"ISIS calls on supporters in Israel to launch new terror attacks"

https://www.i24news.tv/en/news/israel/defense/1650270526-isis-calls-on-supporters-in-israel-to-launch-new-terror-attacks